# Remove Multi-Line String from File with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am attempting to remove a string from a file using Powershell. The string is from another file.

My code can successfully read the file but not remove the string from the other file. Whats going wrong and how can I fix it?

```
$inputFile          = ".\usermenuTest1.4d"
$outputFile         = ".\usermenuTest2.4d"
$destinationFile    =  "$outputFile.new"

# Read input file into variable
$target  = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($inputFile)

# Replace target in output file
(Get-Content $outputFile) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace $target, ''
    } | Set-Content $destinationFile
```

Comment: Does the string you're replacing span multiple lines?  Your current script processes the contents of $outputFile one line at a time.

Comment: Another issue is if you have regex meta characters in the input file.  In that case, you will need to escape those characters unless you intend them to be used as a regex.

Answer (score 0):

As @KeithHill already pointed out your script currently processes `$outputFile` line-by-line. Try something like this instead:

```
$s = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($outputFile)
$r = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($inputFile)

$s -replace $r, '' | Out-File $destinationFile
```